# Let $A$ be countable. The set $[A]^n:=\{S \subseteq A|| S \mid=n\}$ is countable for all $n \in N, n \neq 0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals

I am solving the following problem:

> Let $A$ be countable. The set $[A]^n:=\{S \subseteq A|| S \mid=n\}$ is countable for all $n \in N, n \neq 0$

I define the function $f:[A]^n\rightarrow N^n$ defined by $f(\left\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\right\}) = \left(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\right)$, this function is 1-1 and $N^n$ is equipotent with $N$ then I have to $|[A]^n|\leq|N|$

how can I get $|N|\leq|[A]^n$|?

if I have $|N|\leq|[A]^n|$ then I could apply the Cantor-Bernstein theorem and $|N|=|[A]^n|$

Comment: Co-domain of $f$ should be $A^n=A\times A\times\dots\times A$ and not $N^n$. Now try to complete the rest of the proof

Comment: For your function from $[A]^n\to A^n$, you need to state that the $a_i$’s are in increasing order (with $A$ ordered by its correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$). Otherwise it’s not 1-1. In the other direction, you can map $a$ to the set of $n$ consecutive elements of $A$ with lowest element $a$.

Comment: By the way, this exercise is not hard to do without using the Cantor-Bernstein theorem. It’s enough to prove the corresponding statement with $A=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: To get $|\mathbb{N}| \leqslant [A]^n$, notice that $[A]^n$ contains the infinite family $\{a,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ where $(a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ is fixed and $a$ browses $A\backslash\{a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ which is infinite.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss Thank you for your answer. I don't understand when you say with lowest element $a$, i.e., The function $h: A \rightarrow [A]^n$ and I define it as $h(a_1) = \left\{a_0, a_2, \ldots, a_n\right\}$ ?

Comment: @Fred Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$. Map $a_i$ to $\{a_i,a_{i+1},\ldots,a_{i+n-1}\}$. Or use Cactus's suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss I am trying to prove that the function you suggested is injective, in this case it is also necessary to indicate that the $a_i$'s are in increasing order? e.i. $a_0<a_1<a_2<...$  right?

Comment: @Fred The order of the $a$’s is determined by the order in which you list the countable set $A$.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss ah, ok as A is a countable set then there is an implicit order in the set A, (for example the order of the natural numbers but in A). (?)

Comment: @MichaelWeiss I think I understand, the elements of A I organized as $a_1,a_2,..., a_n, a_{n+1},...$ , in that particular way I can define the order in A, i.e. $A= \left\{a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n, a_{n+1, \ldots}\right\}$  and that way the order is definite.